# Wire value is not passed properly to submodule

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am currently facing an issue that I hope someone could help me out with. For the `VGADesign` module wrapper in the testbench below, why are the wires (`VGA_HS`) and (`VGA_VS`) shown as 'x' or unknown when I simulate/run it? Am I not passing the values correctly from the `DisplayTimings` module to the `VGADesign` module? I am confused. The issue I am facing here is not obvious to me.

**Testbench**

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps  

module tb_top();

///////////////////////////  parameter list ///////////////////////////
//CLK: 100MHz
parameter       periodCLK_2     = 5; 
parameter       perioddump      = 10;
parameter       delay           = 1;
parameter       delay_in        = 2;
parameter       VTpw             = 1600;
parameter       VTdisp           = 384000;
parameter       VTs              = 416800;
parameter       VTfp             = 23200;
parameter       VTbp             = 8000;
parameter       HTpw             = 96;
parameter       HTdisp           = 640;
parameter       HTs              = 800;
parameter       HTfp             = 48;
parameter       HTbp             = 16;
 
parameter       STpw    = 2'h0;
parameter       STfp    = 2'h1;
parameter       STdisp  = 2'h2;
parameter       STbp    = 2'h3;
 
reg[1:0]          HSyncState;
reg[1:0]          VSyncState;

reg             HStart;
reg             CLK_TB;
reg             RSTN;
reg        [9:0]      X_pos;
reg         [9:0]     Y_pos;
wire[0:0]               HSync;
wire[0:0]               VSync;
reg             de;

 
integer       Clkcount;
integer       HSyncCounts;
integer       VSyncCounts;

wire VGA_B;
wire VGA_G;
wire VGA_R;
wire   VGA_HS;
wire   VGA_VS;
    
  wire clk ;
  wire clk_out;

 
  clk_div clkdivby4(
    .clk(CLK_TB),
    .reset(RSTN),
    .clk_out(clk_out)
 );
 DisplayTimings VGATimings(
    .Clk_px(clk_out ),
    .rst(RSTN),
    .sx(),
    .sy(),
    .Hsync(HSync),
    .Vsync(VSync),
    .de()
 );
 
 VGADesign vga(
    .clk_25Mhz(clk_out),
    .btn_rst(RSTN),
    .vgaHS(VGA_HS),
    .vgaVS(VGA_VS),
    .VGA_R(VGA_R),
    .VGA_G(VGA_G),
    .VGA_B(VGA_B) 
);
 // CLK_TB //
initial 
begin
  CLK_TB = 1'b0;
  #(perioddump);
  CLK_TB = 1'b1;
  forever
  begin
    CLK_TB = !CLK_TB;
    #(periodCLK_2);
  end
end
initial begin
  $display("===================");
  $display("Start Test Scenario");
  $display("===================");
  global_reset();

  repeat(1)  @(posedge CLK_TB); #delay;
 
  repeat(1) @(posedge CLK_TB); #delay;
  
  repeat(10) @(posedge CLK_TB);#delay;
  $display(VGA_HS);
  $display(VGA_VS);
end

task global_reset;
begin
  repeat(2)  @(posedge CLK_TB);   #delay; 

    HStart = 1'b0; 
    VSyncState = 2'h0;
    HSyncState = 2'h0;
//    VSync = 1'b0;
//    HSync = 1'b0;
    VSyncCounts=0;
    HSyncCounts = 0;
    
  repeat(2)  @(posedge CLK_TB); #delay;
  RSTN          = 1'b0;
  
  repeat(2) @(posedge CLK_TB); #delay;
  RSTN          = 1'b1;
 
end
endtask
 
endmodule
```

**Design**

```
module VGADesign(
    input       clk_25Mhz,     // 25 MHz clock
    input       btn_rst,      // reset button (active low)
    output     wire[0:0]  vgaHS,    // horizontal sync
    output     wire[0:0]  vgaVS,    // vertical sync
    output       [3:0] VGA_R,  // 4-bit VGA red
    output       [3:0] VGA_G,  // 4-bit VGA green
    output       [3:0] VGA_B   // 4-bit VGA blue
    );
 
 DisplayTimings VGATimings(
    .Clk_px(clk_25Mhz),
    .rst(RSTN),
    .sx(),
    .sy(),
    .Hsync(vgaHS),
    .Vsync(vgaVS),
    .de()
 );  
   assign VGA_R[0] = 1'b1;
   assign VGA_R[1] = 1'b1;
   assign VGA_R[2] = 1'b1;
   assign VGA_R[3] = 1'b1; 

endmodule

module clk_div(
clk,reset, clk_out
    );
    input clk;
input reset;
output clk_out;
 
reg [1:0] r_reg;
wire [1:0] r_nxt;
reg clk_track;
 
always @(posedge clk)
 
begin
  if (!reset)
     begin
        r_reg <= 3'b0;
    clk_track <= 1'b0;
     end
 
  else if (r_nxt == 2'b10)
       begin
         r_reg <= 0;
         clk_track <= ~clk_track;
       end
 
  else 
      r_reg <= r_nxt;
end
 
 assign r_nxt = r_reg+1;          
 assign clk_out = clk_track;
    
endmodule

`timescale 1ns / 1ps


module DisplayTimings(
    input   Clk_px,   // pixel clock
    input    rst,       // reset
    output  [9:0] sx,  // horizontal screen position
    output  [9:0] sy,  // vertical screen position
    output   Hsync,     // horizontal sync
    output   Vsync,     // vertical sync
    output  de         // data enable (low in blanking interval)

    );
 reg[0:0] Hsync;    
 reg[0:0] Vsync;    
 parameter VTdisp = 384000;
 parameter VTpw = 1600;
 parameter VTfp = 8000;
 parameter VTbp = 23200;
 
 parameter HTdisp = 640;
 parameter HTpw = 96;
 parameter HTfp = 16;
 parameter HTbp = 48;
 
 reg     [1:0]Vstate;
 reg     [1:0]Hstate;
 integer      Clkcnt;
 integer      Vcnt;
 integer      Hcnt;
parameter Vfp = 0, Vpw = 1, Vdisp = 2, Vbp = 3;
parameter Hfp = 0, Hpw = 1, Hdisp = 2, Hbp = 3;

 
 always @(posedge Clk_px or negedge rst) begin
    if (!rst) begin 
        Vcnt = 0;
        Hcnt = 0;
        Clkcnt =0;
        Vsync <= 1'b0;
        Hsync <= 1'b0;
        Vstate <= Vfp;
        Hstate <= Hfp;
    end 
    else begin
        case (Vstate)   
           Vfp: begin
               Vcnt = Vcnt+1; 
              if(Vcnt == VTfp) begin
                Vcnt = 0;
                Vstate <= Vpw;
                Vsync <= 1'b0;
                end
              end
           Vpw: begin
           Vcnt = Vcnt+1; 
              if (Vcnt == VTpw) begin 
                 Vcnt = 0;
                 Vstate <= Vdisp; 
                 Vsync <= 1'b1;
              end
             end
           Vdisp: begin
              Vcnt = Vcnt+1; 
              if (Vcnt == VTdisp)begin
                 Vcnt = 0;
                 Vstate <= Vbp;  
              end   
              end
           Vbp: begin
           Vcnt = Vcnt+1; 
              if (Vcnt == VTbp) begin
                 Vcnt = 0;
                 Vstate <= Vfp; 
              end  
            end
        endcase
        case (Hstate)
          Hfp:begin
              Hcnt = Hcnt + 1; 
              if(Hcnt == HTfp) begin
                Hcnt = 0;
                Hstate <= Hpw;
                Hsync <= 1'b0;
                end
             end
           Hpw: begin
               Hcnt = Hcnt + 1;
    
              if (Hcnt == HTpw) begin 
                 Hcnt = 0;
                 Hstate <= Hdisp; 
                 Hsync <= 1'b1;
              end
            end
           Hdisp: begin
               Hcnt = Hcnt + 1;
    
              if (Hcnt == HTdisp)begin
                 Hcnt = 0;
                 Hstate <= Hbp;  
              end  
           end 
           Hbp:begin
               Hcnt = Hcnt + 1;
    
              if (Hcnt == HTbp) begin
                 Hcnt = 0;
                 Hstate <= Hfp; 
              end  
            end 
        endcase  
     end
 end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signals are unknown because they are not reset properly.  You have a connection bug.  I get this compile warning:

```
    .rst(RSTN),
            |
xmelab: *W,CSINFI : implicit wire has no fanin (tb_top.vga.RSTN).
```

Change:

```
.rst(RSTN),
```

to:

```
.rst(btn_rst),
```

This eliminates the unknowns for me.

If you do not get a similar warning, you should try your code on edaplayground, where several simulators are available for free.

---

Note: I see other warnings as well.